# SQL Page Life Expectancy cntr_value is in seconds or ms?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just wondering if the value that you get through the sys.dm_os_performance_counters for Page Life Expectancy is in seconds or ms. 
If I run it for a SQL Server that does not have much use, I get **245073** in cntr_value, which seems to be a super high value to be considered in seconds.

```
SELECT * 
        FROM
            sys.dm_os_performance_counters
        WHERE
            object_name LIKE '%MSSQLSERVER2012:Buffer Manager%'
            AND counter_name = 'Page life expectancy'
```

Comment: Wait one second, try again. You'll see the value really is in seconds. A high value merely means your server is able to keep data in memory, which is a good thing. This value can be high even on a heavily used server.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, thank you so much @JeroenMostert.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2013/09/23/interpreting-the-counter-values-from-sys-dm_os_performance_counters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PLE (Page Life Expectancy) is expressed in seconds. The metric can be useful to understand the memory pressure of your server.

However, you should have a look at PLE only in a wider context, as having plenty of memory does not necessarily mean that the server is performing well.

For further information, please have a look at this question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203784/page-life-expectancy-ple-where-to-start), where there is a more detailed explanation.